# Integrate EventEmitter in Object construtor to use in prototype methods

Tags: javascript, node.js, eventemitter

I have the following, strange problem:
I wrote a "Class" Game. This Class has a constructor and one prototype method. I want the whole construct to be an EventEmitter. So I thought I could just inherit the event.EventEmitter for my constructor. 
It looked first as follows:

game.js

```
var EventEmitter  = require('events').EventEmitter;
var util          = require('util');

/*
  Game factory
*/

function Game(catalogue, speed) {

  //EventEmitter.call(this);

  this.catalogue  = catalogue || null;
  this.speed      = speed || 10;  

}

Game.prototype.listen = function(){
  var self = this;
  setInterval(function(){
    self.emit('init', 0);
  }, 500);
}

util.inherits(Game, EventEmitter);
module.exports = Game;
```

I use socket.io to connect to the client. In my main socket routine I use the following code to start a new game (instantiate)

controller.js

```
socket.on('startGame', function(){      

  var myGame = new Game('default', 10);
  myGame.init();

  myGame.on('init', function(status){
    console.log('Did start with status code: ', status);
  });
};
```

This does not work as expected.Error is:

```
Missing error handler on `socket`.
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at Socket.<anonymous>
```

When I use the emit event in the constructor, it works (without myGame.listen() in the console.js, of course):

```
function Game(catalogue, speed) {


  //EventEmitter.call(this);

  this.catalogue  = catalogue || null;
  this.speed      = speed || 10;  

  var self = this;
  setInterval(function(){
    self.emit('init', (Math.random()*10).toFixed(0));
  }, 500)

}
```

So what is wrong here? 
Note that I don't need

```
EventEmitter.call(this);
```

in the constructor in the second example.
But independent from commenting this out or leaving it in, this downs change anything. 
Why do I need this at all? Do I?

Maybe you can help. Kind regard.
Martin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to move your `util.inherits(Game, EventEmitter);` to *before* you start adding functions to your prototype. The `util.inherits()` meddles with the prototype, so anything placed on it before then is lost.

Additionally, when you inherit from another object (like `EventEmitter`), you really should call the parent constructor (`EventEmitter.call(this)`) because it may need to do some initialization of its own.

Answer (score 0):

Updated example with Node.js v11.12.0

```
const EventEmitter = require('events');

module.exports = class Game extends EventEmitter {
    constructor(catalogue, speed) {
        super();
        this.catalogue = catalogue || null;
        this.speed = speed || 10;
    }

    listen() {
        setInterval(() => {
            self.emit('init', 0);
        }, 500);
    }
};

let myGame = new Game('default', 10);
myGame.listen();
myGame.on('init', status => {
    console.log('Did start with status code: ', status);
});
```

Some neat new stuff here.

- Don't need require('events').EventEmitter suffix part anymore. It is still available for backwards compatibility.
- Can use class and extends.
- Can use arrow functions in the setInterval which implicitly binds to `this` instead of needing to map this to self.